# Convert raw SQL to SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_stocks 
WHERE detected_date = (
                         SELECT MAX(detected_date) 
                         FROM product_stocks 
                         WHERE id = 18865
                      ) 
      AND id = 18865;
```

Having lots of trouble converting this to SQLAlchemy query string. What's the most efficient way?

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficient way"? Are you trying to optimize the query before you even know how to build it?

Comment: Also, are you using the SQLAlchemy ORM, or just the query expression language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below will recreated the SQL you asked for:

```
_id = 18865
T = aliased(ProductStock, name="T")
T1 = aliased(ProductStock, name="T1")
subquery = (
    session.query(func.max(T1.detected_date).label("detected_date"))
    .filter(T1.id == _id)
    # .filter(T1.id == T.id)  # @note: i prefer this one to the line above
    .as_scalar()
)
qry = (
    session.query(T)
    .filter(T.detected_date == subquery)
    .filter(T.id == _id)
)
```

Is this the most efficient way to accomplish what you want? - I am not so sure, but not enough information

Answer (score 11):

You can  use `from_statement` to execute the raw SQL-Query and fetch it in a SQL-Alchemy Object. This helps when it's easier to write plain SQL then SQLAlchemy Syntax.

```
Session.query(YourClass).from_statement(text('''SELECT * FROM product_stocks 
WHERE detected_date = (SELECT MAX(detected_date) FROM product_stocks WHERE id = 18865)
AND id = 18865;''')).all()
```

Comment: Would you know how to do this from classic SQLAlchemy?

Comment: didn't used SQLAlchemy in a long time. But as far as I remember this was the way to do it. Not sure what you mean with classic SQL alchemy. But maybe you mean the short handle for a specific Model which only replaces the `Session.query(class)`. Rest should be the same. And it is only about on what Object you want to bind the data. But I could be wrong because as I said I didn't use it in a long time.

Comment: In case someone runs into problems with this, I found the following answer to be useful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344728/sqlalchemy-from-statement-cannot-locate-column

Comment: exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

With Core SQLAlchemy 1.4/2.0:

```py
from sqlalchemy import text, select, column
sql = 'SELECT foo FROM bar'
sql = text(sql)
sql = sql.columns(column('foo'))  # This let's it be used as a subquery

sel = select(sql.selected_columns.foo).select_from(sql.subquery())

joined = sel.outerjoin(baz_t, baz_t.foo==sel.c.foo)

final = select(sel.c.foo).select_from(joined)
```

With Core SQLAlchemy < 1.4:

```py
sql = 'SELECT foo FROM bar'
sql = text(sql)
sql = sql.columns()  # This let's it be used as a subquery

sel = select(['foo']).select_from(sql)
# I needed this for a complex query or else columns would be ambiguous
sel = sel.alias('sel')  

joined = sel.outerjoin(baz_t, baz_t.foo==sel.c.foo)

final = select([sel.c.foo]).select_from(joined)
```

Note that the `columns()` is necessary, and the `alias()` is helpful if the query is complex.

The following [text](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) documentation is helpful.

Comment: just tried this out, did not work for me

Comment: @Saikathalder You are probably using SQLAlchemy 2.0. This answer was written 5 years ago. I've added an untested update. Perhaps you should mention what error you receive next time?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It did not exactly work for me, but I found solution by playing around from your answer.